# Does this.setState really make component re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

something about this.setState in class components is confusing me. in react docs, i read that this.setState may be asynchronous in react docs. im okay with this and i tested it with logging the updated value after this.setState. but it is really confusing me: when we call this.setState, react calls render method of the class to re-render the ui. but this.setState is asynchronous and it means that first render method will be called and ui will be re-rendered by react, then the value in the state will be changed! so how does component show us the updated value? i dont... am i thinking right?
thanks for helping.

Comment: Showing us the logging code that's confusing you might help answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> this.setState is asynchronous and it means that first render method will be called and ui will be re-rendered by react, then the value in the state will be changed! so how does component show us the updated value? i dont... am i thinking right?

I think you missed something.setState is asynchronous which means that the actions are batched together for performance gains . But why ? since it's not a a WebAPI or server call?
This is because setState alters the state and causes rerendering. This can be an expensive operation and making it synchronous might leave the browser to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: maybe this will helps you more - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710

Comment: sorry but im still confused... you mean for example if we call setState 4 times in a function, react first collect those 4 setState and then make them one update instead of 4 updates so the component re-renders 1 time instead of 4 times? if yes, how? how does react collect setStates and run those? so react first look for other setStates in the function and then change the state and re-render the component? i still dont understand this...

Comment: What's your doubt then ?

Comment: can you please tell me an example of asynchronous with using setState? here asynchronous means that setStates will be collected by react and and then react re-render the UI just once or it has other meaning in this situation? i dont get it. thanks for answering.